# customize xml serialization and xsd generation for certain types in c#

Tags: .net, xml

I need to generate xml schema (using Xsd.exe, XmlReflectionImporter or something similar) and implement serialization for existing code base.

How can I customize xml mapping and provide custom serialization routines WITHOUT modifying existing code.

For example given existing non-serializable class `Foo` I would like to write its serializable variant `FooData` and specify somewhere that it should be used instead and also provide conversion methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that newer WCF DataContracts give more control over serialization, specifically [surrogates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064.aspx) do exactly what I need.